# How to mark a drop down selected from within an object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, select, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am currently struggling–I'm new to javascript and am having trouble writing a small script. I am trying to create a quiz in Business Catalyst.

I have set up each question as an object and create an array with each question's dynamic properties assigned when the page loads.

On the same page I have a submission form that logs the user's answers along with the question's text and values. The issue I am struggling with is that I have four different answer types for the quiz/survey. I want to mark the correct answer type on a drop down list when the page loads. I have tried about 15 different scripts to get the selected value to be logged, but cannot figure out a definitive way to mark it. I keep getting various errors that lead me to believe it is because I am trying to run the script from within the object.

Below is my code, note that any {tag} items you see are a business catalyst way of inserting dynamic text. Also the specific script I am struggling with is at the end of the object (this.getAnswerType). I also have additional scripts on the page but for the sake of saving space I've excluded them.

If anyone could help me understand how to get the right script to work and why it works I would be grateful. Thank you!

```
    var quizSurvey = "{tag_quiz/survey}";
    function Question(questionNumber, questionText, answerType, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctAnswer, visualRef, refKey, nextQ, qTextField, aTypeField, mcAField, mcBField, mcCField, mcDField, mcUserAnswerField, tfUserAnswerField, sRatings, sSAnswer, passFail, sAnswerType) {
    this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.answerType = answerType;
    this.answerA = answerA;
    this.answerB = answerB;
    this.answerC = answerC;
    this.answerD = answerD;
    this.true = "True";
    this.false = "False";
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.visualRef = visualRef;
    this.refKey = refKey;
    this.nextQ = nextQ;
    this.qTextField = qTextField;
    this.aTypeField = aTypeField;
    this.mcAField = mcAField;
    this.mcBField = mcBField;
    this.mcCField = mcCField;
    this.mcDField = mcDField;
    this.mcUserAnswerField = mcUserAnswerField;
    this.tfUserAnswerField = tfUserAnswerField;
    this.sRatings = sRatings;
    this.sSAnswer = sSAnswer;
    this.passFail = passFail;
    this.sAnswerType = sAnswerType;
    this.answer = "";
    this.vimeo = "";
    this.youtube = "";
    this.img = "";
    this.layoutVimeo = "";
    this.visual = "";
    this.getAnswerType = function() {
        dropdown = document.getElementById(this.aTypeField);
        valueToSet = this.answerType;
            for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.options.length; i++) {
                if (dropdown.options[i].text == valueToSet) {
                    dropdown.options[i].selected = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
};
var question = new Array();
question[0] = new Question(1, "{tag_q-question_1}", "{tag_q-answer-type_1}", "{tag_q-text-answer_101}", "{tag_q-text-answer_102}", "{tag_q-text-answer_103}", "{tag_q-text-answer_104}", "{tag_q-multichoice-answer_1}{tag_q-t/f-answer_1}", "{tag_q-visual-reference_1}", "{tag_q-youtube_1}{tag_q-vimeo_1}{tag_q-image_1_value}", "{tag_q-next-question_1}", "CAT_Custom_13", "CAT_Custom_11", "CAT_Custom_14", "CAT_Custom_15", "CAT_Custom_16", "CAT_Custom_17", "CAT_Custom_7", "CAT_Custom_8", "CAT_Custom_9", "CAT_Custom_10", "CAT_Custom_12", "{tag_s-answer-type_1}");
question[1] = new Question(2, "{tag_q-question_2}", "{tag_q-answer-type_2}", "{tag_q-text-answer_201}", "{tag_q-text-answer_202}", "{tag_q-text-answer_203}", "{tag_q-text-answer_204}", "{tag_q-multichoice-answer_2}{tag_q-t/f-answer_2}", "{tag_q-visual-reference_2}", "{tag_q-youtube_2}{tag_q-vimeo_2}{tag_q-image_2_value}", "{tag_q-next-question_2}", "CAT_Custom_19", "CAT_Custom_20", "CAT_Custom_22", "CAT_Custom_23", "CAT_Custom_24", "CAT_Custom_25", "CAT_Custom_21", "CAT_Custom_26", "CAT_Custom_27", "CAT_Custom_28", "CAT_Custom_29", "{tag_s-answer-type_2}");
```

And I call the script here:

```
if (quizSurvey == "Quiz") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        if (question[i].questionText != "") {
            question[i].visRefType();
            question[i].createQuestion();
            allQuestions = allQuestions + 1;
            question[i].getAnswerType();
        } else {

        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the `value` property of the `option`s in order to determine which OPTION to select. I've found browsers to be a tad wonky in this regard. Generally I set the `selected` property of an option, as well as the `selectedIndex` of the dropdown itself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.options.length; i++) {
    if (dropdown.options[i].value == valueToSet) {
        dropdown.options[i].selected = true;
        dropdown.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I received the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null'

Comment: Well, that would be the problem. :) The call to `document.getElementById` is returning a null value.

Comment: The call to `dropdown = document.getElementById(this.aTypeField);` is returning a `null` value. The HTML tag Id referenced by `this.aTypeField` doesn't appear to exist on the page at the time that code runs.